# C# regex for negated character class unless chars are next to one another

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I need to match the characters between the innermost set of parentheses in a string, but allowing empty parens such as '()'. As best I can tell some kind of negative lookahead is needed here (and it is completely different than the question for which it is marked as duplicate)

An initial version, which does *not* properly include '()' is:

```
var re = new Regex(@"\(([^()]+)\)");
```

Some test examples:

```
x (a) y          -> a
x (a b) y        -> a b
x (a b c) y      -> a b c
x (a b() c) y    -> a b() c
x (a() b() c) y  -> a() b() c
x (a b() c()) y  -> a b() c()
x (a b(a) c) y   -> a
x (a (b() c)) y  -> b() c
x () y           -> empty
```

And a c# test method (adapt for your assertion library):

```cs
var re = new Regex(@"\(([^()]+)\)");

string[] tests = {
    "x (a) y", "a",
    "x (a b) y", "a b",
    "x (a b c) y", "a b c",
    "x (a b() c) y", "a b() c",
    "x (a() b() c) y", "a() b() c",
    "x (a b() c()) y", "a b() c()",
    "x (a b(a) c) y", "a",
    "x (a (b() c)) y", "b() c",
    "x () y", ""
};

for (int i = 0; i < tests.Length; i+=2)
{
    var match = re.Match(tests[i]);
    var result = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(tests[i + 1]));
}
```

Comment: Research capture groups.  Once you have that piece of the puzzle, you should be able to fit the rest.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew I think you may have missed something here. First, your regex is not a valid answer (see the test cases). Second, this is a very different question than the one for which you have marked it as duplicate. How can I edit the question to make this more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this: *(No need for Lookarounds)*

```
\(((?:[^()]|\(\))+)\)
```

**The adjustments made to your regex:**

Added the `[^()]` in a non-capturing group along with an alternative `|\(\)` so it can match **either** a character other than `(` and `)` **or** empty parentheses `()`.

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/qCYTQu/1).

Alternatively, you could get rid of the capturing group *if you don't need it* and have your matches in full matches instead of groups by using Lookarounds like this:

```
(?<=\()(?:[^()]|\(\))+(?=\))
```

That way, you can access your matches directly using `match.Value` instead of `match.Groups[1].Value`.

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/h4Bzml/1).

Please let me know if there's anything not clear.

Comment: Nice -- please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560112/matching-balanced-parentheses-before-a-character