# Matching balanced parentheses before a character

Tags: c#, regex, balanced-groups

I need to match a string within balanced parentheses before a literal period in c#. My regex with balanced groups works *except* when there are extra open parens in the string. According to my understanding, this requires a conditional fail pattern to ensure the stack is empty on match, yet something is not quite right.

Original regex:

`@"(?<Par>[(]).+(?<-Par>[)])\."`

With fail-pattern:

`@"(?<Par>[(]).+(?<-Par>[)])(?(Par)(?!))\."`

Test-code (last 2 fail):

```
string[] tests = {
    "a.c",   "",
    "a).c",  "",
    "(a.c",  "",
    "a(a).c", "(a).",
    "a(a b).c", "(a b).",
    "a((a b)).c", "((a b)).",
    "a(((a b))).c", "(((a b))).",
    "a((a) (b)).c", "((a) (b)).",
    "a((a)(b)).c", "((a)(b)).",
    "a((ab)).c", "((ab)).",
    "a)((ab)).(c", "((ab)).",
    "a(((a b)).c", "((a b)).", 
    "a(((a b)).)c", "((a b))."
};

Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<Par>[(]).+(?<-Par>[)])(?(Par)(?!))\.");

for (int i = 0; i < tests.Length; i += 2)
{
    var result = re.Match(tests[i]).Groups[0].Value;
    if (result != tests[i + 1]) throw new Exception
        ("Expecting: " + tests[i + 1] + ", got " + result);
}
```

Comment: https://www.xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: Just in case this is a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) can you share _why_ you are trying to do this?

Comment: In my opinion do notnuse Regex for Parenthesis Balance problem. Go the crude Stack way.

Comment: You seem to love regex horrors, considering this is the second question about regexes and balanced parentheses

Comment: I think it is a classical case of using a balanced construct with a `.` after it, so [`\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)\.`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%28%29%5cn%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%29%5c%28%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%29%5c%29%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29%5c%29%5c.&i=a%28a+b%29.c%22%2c+%22%28a+b%29.%22%2c%0d%0a) should work.

Comment: nice - add it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @rednoyz Ok, posted. Looks like `\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))*(?(o)(?!))\)\.` is the faster version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a well-known regex to match balanced parentheses and just append a `\.` to it:

```
\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)\.
|---------- balanced parens part ----------|.|
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5Cn%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%5C.&i=a.c%22%2C%20%20%20%22%22%2C%0D%0Aa%29.c%22%2C%20%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%28a.c%22%2C%20%20%22%22%2C%0D%0Aa%28a%29.c%22%2C%20%22%28a%29.%22%2C%0D%0Aa%28a%20b%29.c%22%2C%20%22%28a%20b%29.%22%2C%0D%0Aa%28%28a%20b%29%29.c%22%2C%20%22%28%28a%20b%29%29.%22%2C%0D%0Aa%28%28%28a%20b%29%29%29.c%22%2C%20%22%28%28%28a%20b%29%29%29.%22%2C%0D%0Aa%28%28a%29%20%28b%29%29.c%22%2C%20%22%28%28a%29%20%28b%29%29.%22%2C%0D%0Aa%28%28a%29%28b%29%29.c%22%2C%20%22%28%28a%29%28b%29%29.%22%2C%0D%0Aa%28%28ab%29%29.c%22%2C%20%22%28%28ab%29%29.%22%2C%0D%0Aa%29%28%28ab%29%29.%28c%22%2C%20%22%28%28ab%29%29.%22%2C%0D%0Aa%28%28%28a%20b%29%29.c%22%2C%20%22%28%28a%20b%29%29.%22%2C%20%0D%0Aa%28%28%28a%20b%29%29.%29c%22%2C%20%22%28%28a%20b%29%29.%22).

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(`
- `(?>` - start of an atomic group

  - `[^()]+` - 1 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<o>)\(` - an opening `(` is pushed on to the Group `o` stack
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<-o>)\)` - a closing `(` is popped off the Group `o` stack
- `)*` - 0 or more repetitions of the atomic group
- `(?(o)(?!))` - fail the match if Group `o` stack is not empty
- `\)` - a `)`
- `\.` - a dot.

Comment: Just tested at RegexHero.net, and it appears that the pattern will work faster if you include `\(` and `\)` into Group "o": `\((?>[^()]+|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))*(?(o)(?!))\)\.`